# Python list printing utf-8 literals for the contained dictionary elements with HINDI text

Tags: python, list, dictionary, encoding, utf-8

I am working with Python 2.7 and I am a beginner. I am facing problem in printing a list with dict objects containing Hindi strings.

I have a list containing several dictionary objects as here:

```
[{u'text': u'+4a41+'}, {u'text': u'+4a42+'}, {u'text': u'+4a43+'}, {u'text': u'+4a44+'}, {u'text': u'+4a45+'}]
```

Each contained object one element and corresponding to the key `'text'`, there is 'string id'. In the list above, for first dict element, string id is `4a41`.

I read these string ids and lookup in a dictionary to find the string corresponding to the id and replace the id with the string. My dictionary contains Hindi strings. When I fetch and print the string values, they are printed correctly but when I add them to the dict objects and put them in a list, printing the list shows utf characters and not the actual Hindi text.

I am posting a sample output below:

```
[{u'text': u'+4a41+'}, {u'text': u'+4a42+'}, {u'text': u'+4a43+'}, {u'text': u'+4a44+'}, {u'text': u'+4a45+'}]  

ENCODING:  {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}  
DICT ITEM 142 डिनर के बाद चहलकदमी को पारिवारिक परंपरा बनाएं   

ENCODING:  {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}  
DICT ITEM 142 प्रत्येक 30 मिनट पर उठें और चलें-फिरें  

ENCODING:  {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}  
DICT ITEM 142 किसी पड़ोसी से मिलने जाते समय चल कर जाएं  

ENCODING:  {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}  
DICT ITEM 142 किसी मित्र के साथ रोजाना सुबह टहलने की योजना बनाएं  

ENCODING:  {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}  
DICT ITEM 142 अपने लक्ष्य के आधे चरणों को दोपहर तक करने की कोशिश करें  

return_list [{u'text': '\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa6 \xe0\xa4\x9a\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8b \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95 \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\x82\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbe \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x8f\xe0\xa4\x82'}, {u'text': '\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\x95 30 \xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\x9f \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\x89\xe0\xa4\xa0\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\x82 \xe0\xa4\x94\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\x9a\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\x82-\xe0\xa4\xab\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\x82'}, {u'text': '\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xbc\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa4\xaf \xe0\xa4\x9a\xe0\xa4\xb2 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x8f\xe0\xa4\x82'}, {u'text': '\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa5 \xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe \xe0\xa4\xb8\xe0\xa5\x81\xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xb9 \xe0\xa4\x9f\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\x9c\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x8f\xe0\xa4\x82'}, {u'text': '\xe0\xa4\x85\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xb7\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\x86\xe0\xa4\xa7\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\x9a\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xa3\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\x82 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8b \xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa4\x95 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb6\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb6 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa5\x87\xe0\xa4\x82'}]
```

In the output above, first line is the list containing the dictionary object with string ids.

below that I'm printing the encoding of the string and the value of the string fetched from the dictionary. So the lines starting with **ENCODING:** show the encoding of the string displayed in the line just below it starting with **DICT ITEM 142**

In the end, the list with replaced values is shown.

The expected output is:

```
return_list [{u'text': 'डिनर के बाद चहलकदमी को पारिवारिक परंपरा बनाएं'}, {u'text': 'प्रत्येक 30 मिनट पर उठें और चलें-फिरें'}, {u'text': 'किसी पड़ोसी से मिलने जाते समय चल कर जाएं'}, {u'text': 'किसी मित्र के साथ रोजाना सुबह टहलने की योजना बनाएं'}, {u'text': 'अपने लक्ष्य के आधे चरणों को दोपहर तक करने की कोशिश करें'}]
```

My question is that printing the dictionary elements prints the Hindi strings correctly but once I append these to a list and print the list, it prints utf literals. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary contains strings with *UTF-8 bytes*. Python 2 will always use `\xhh` when representing such bytes in debug output, including when showing dictionary contents (for which the `repr()` function output is used).

Python does this to make your debug output suitable for recreating the original value simply by copying and pasting into any Python interpreter session or new script, while not having to worry about terminal or editor configurations beyond supporting ASCII.

You see the same thing when echoing the string object in an interactive session:

```
>>> text = 'डिनर के बाद चहलकदमी को पारिवारिक परंपरा बनाएं'
>>> print text
डिनर के बाद चहलकदमी को पारिवारिक परंपरा बनाएं
>>> text
'\xe0\xa4\xa1\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xb0 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x87 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xa6 \xe0\xa4\x9a\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa4\xb2\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa4\xae\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8b \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\x95 \xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\x82\xe0\xa4\xaa\xe0\xa4\xb0\xe0\xa4\xbe \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x8f\xe0\xa4\x82'
```

If you must print the original bytes directly to your terminal, don't print the dictionary. You'll have to do your own formatting to avoid being given `repr()` output.

Comment: Thank you so much. Iterating through the reconstructed list and printing the values from the dict objects, I'm able to print the values.